# For loop runs only 1 time instead of 2 times as it should

Tags: python, for-loop, praw

I have a list of 2 lines, first one should trigget the "post.locked" part of the code and the next line should trigger the "else" part.

If I run this code then it will only print out the "if" part but not the "else" part. Why?

```
    for post in reddit.subreddit(content[nr].rstrip()).new(limit = 1):
        if post.locked:
            content[nr] = content[nr + 1]
            print(post.permalink)
        else:
            print(post.permalink)
            content[nr] = content[nr + 1]
            break
```

Comment: You can find out by adding print(post.locked) just above the 'if'

Comment: Assuming reddit.subreddit(content[nr].rstrip()).new(limit = 1) be an iterable, and post being the value at a particular index. Try print(reddit.subreddit(content[nr].rstrip()).new(limit = 1)[1]) , either you'll end up in an index exception or you'll get a falsy value.

Comment: Why would `limit = 1` return more than one item?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the limit is to get 1 post from reddit but the "content" consist of two lines

Comment: Okay, but you're not looping over content in the shown code

Comment: @quamrana it prints out "True" which it should

Comment: @pyskmr I get "'ListingGenerator' object is not subscriptable" when trying to print "print(reddit.subreddit(content[nr].rstrip()).new(limit = 1)[1])"

Comment: @OneCricketeer how should I change my code then?

Comment: Well, `for c in content` or `for nr in range(len(content))` would be a good start.... In other words, you're not showing us a [mcve] because content and nr are not defined, so we don't know what you're trying to do. Obviously the shown code only loops once because that's what you've set as the limit parameter

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was an idiot - I had to put the whole thing in another for loop like this:

```
    for line in content:
    for post in reddit.subreddit(content[nr].rstrip()).new(limit = 1):
        if post.locked:
            content[nr] = content[nr + 1]
            print("if" + post.permalink)
            print(content[nr])
        else:
            print("else" + post.permalink)
            content[nr] = content[nr + 1]
```